# Changing the appearance of D3 links

Tags: javascript, tree, data-visualization, d3.js

I want to visualize data as a tree, but also I want to customize default link appearance. [There](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/cluster.html) shown default appearance, but I want to create links which looks like [Rational Software Architect](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/dm-0708chang/figure01.jpg) links. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it with writing my own path handler. Here is the sample code:

```
function elbow(d) {
        var radius = 10;

        var xOffsetSign = Math.sign(d.source.x - d.target.x);
        var yOffsetSign = Math.sign(d.source.y - d.target.y);

        if (xOffsetSign != 0) {
            var ellipseXDirection = (xOffsetSign * yOffsetSign) > 0 ? 1 : 0;

            return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y
                + " H" + (d.target.x + xOffsetSign * radius)
                + " A" + radius + "," + radius + " 0 0," + ellipseXDirection + " " + d.target.x + "," + (d.source.y - yOffsetSign * radius)
                + " V" + d.target.y
                + (d.target.children ? "" : "h" + margin.right);
        } else {
            return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y
                + " H" + d.target.x + " V" + d.target.y
                + (d.target.children ? "" : "h" + margin.right);
        }
    }
```

**Function Math.sign is my own implementation**

Answer (score 1):

The links are SVG path elements. You can style them using [CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StyleAttribute) to change the color, width etc. For the arrow heads, you can use [SVG Markers](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#Markers). To add labels, you would need to add additional SVG text elements. You could for example add a new select with the tree [links](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout#wiki-links) as data that create the SVG text elements for the UML cardinality.